# Which are the Listner to be used for firebase databse?

Tags: java, android

After many time of googling i coming here with question about firebase listner. I know little bit that listner use for getting data from database. I want know that which and when listner used for child and its value which are changing every time ?
Please suggest any doc to differentiate that listner briefly with example 
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although your question looks valid at first sight it does not meet SO [minimal site criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please check a forum for this type of question. Enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this type listner to get realtime value from firebase server :-

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(chatListTableName);

        mDatabaseReference.child(groupImageTable).child(groupId)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Glide.with(GroupProfile.this).load(dataSnapshot.child("groupImageUrl")
                                .getValue()).into(userImage);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: I also heard about some child event and single value event listner of firebase ...what is that brother ?

Comment: child event listner is only update you when your table parent child update and  addValueEventListener will update you when any child is update from whole the table

Comment: please suggest any doc to define all listner in brief

Comment: you can read the firebase official instruction the link is this :- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: is this valuable for you ?

Comment: no too much brother. i cant differentiate the listener

Comment: ok than which types listner to be used for getting data from firebase ?

Comment: addValueEventListener for real time data and addListenerForSingleValueEvent for to get data only single time and addChildEventListener is used for if there any child added, child changed, child removed, child moved from its position these are the three types of listners you can used for retrieve data from firebase raltime database

Comment: ok thanx got it

Comment: I seen in many thread, video and blog that people are using model class, adapter, and view holder class to retriving data from firebase. So how it different with ValueEventListener?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

}
```

In this method you used according your requirement get notification and manage it.